# Travelling to a different Schengen country than the Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen, germany, france, schengen-visas

I am the spouse of a UK citizen and have been granted a Schengen visa for Germany. However due to some of my plans falling through, I will no longer be visiting Germany. I was wondering if it's OK for me to visit France on this visa with my spouse or if I need to wait and apply for a French Schengen visa.

Thanks

Comment: Are you traveling with your spouse?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: I can't post an answer because the question has been closed as a duplicate, but as a spouse traveling with your EU-citizen spouse, under European freedom of movement, it really doesn't matter very much.